# Extremely slow scraping with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a Python script to scrape data from IMDb using the Scrapy library. The script is working fine but it is very slow and seems to be getting stuck. I have added a DOWNLOAD_DELAY of 1 second between requests but it doesn't seem to help. Here is the script:

```
import scrapy
import json

class MoviesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'movies'
    allowed_domains = ['www.imdb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096463/fullcredits/']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1  # add a delay of 1  seconds between requests
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get movie information
        movie_year = response.css("img.poster::attr(alt)").extract_first().split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
        movie_name = response.css('meta[property="og:title"]::attr(content)').extract_first().split("(")[0]
        movie_id = response.url.split("/")[4]
        

        # Iterate over actors
        for i, actor in enumerate(response.css("table.cast_list tr")):
            actor_id = actor.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first()
            if actor_id:
                actor_id = actor_id.split("/")[-2]
                actor_name = actor.css("img::attr(title)").extract_first()

                # Get role name
                role_selector = f"table.cast_list tr:nth-child({i+1}) td.character a"
                actor_role = response.css(role_selector + "::text").extract_first()
                actor_role = actor_role.strip() if actor_role else None

                # Build movie data
                movie_data = {
                    "movie_id": movie_id,
                    "movie_name": movie_name,
                    "movie_year": movie_year,
                    "actor_id": actor_id,
                    "actor_name": actor_name,
                    "role_name": actor_role
                }

                # Follow actor page
                next_page = f"https://www.imdb.com/name/{actor_id}"
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_actor_bio,
                                      meta={'movie_data': movie_data})

    def parse_actor_bio(self, response):
        
        response.css(".ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content ::text").extract()

        movie_data = response.meta['movie_data']
        date_place_info = response.css('ul li:contains("Born") ::text').extract()[1:]

        born_date = "".join(date_place_info[0:3])
        born_place = "".join(date_place_info[3:])
        

        # Build result object
        result = {
            "movie_id": movie_data['movie_id'],
            "movie_name": movie_data['movie_name'],
            "movie_year": movie_data['movie_year'],
            "actor_id": movie_data['actor_id'],
            "actor_name": movie_data['actor_name'],
            "role_name": movie_data['role_name'],
            "born_date": born_date,
            "born_place": born_place
        }

        yield json.loads(json.dumps(result))

        movie_links = [x.split("/")[2] for x in response.css('a[href^="/title/"]::attr(href)').extract()]
        movie_links = list(set(movie_links))
        for movie_link in movie_links:
            yield response.follow(f"https://www.imdb.com/title/{movie_link}/fullcredits/", callback=self.parse)
```

However, it is extremely slow.
Some logs:

```
2023-04-11 18:54:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.imdb.com/name/nm14444245/>
{'movie_id': 'tt5640060', 'movie_name': 'Chicago Justice ', 'movie_year': 'TV Series 2017', 'actor_id': 'nm14444245', 'actor_name': 'Matt Abbott', 'role_name': 'Juror', 'born_date': '', 'born_place': ''}
2023-04-11 18:54:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0811523/>
{'movie_id': 'tt0102975', 'movie_name': 'Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country ', 'movie_year': '1991', 'actor_id': 'nm0811523', 'actor_name': 'Michael Snyder', 'role_name': 'Crewman Dax', 'born_date': '', 'born_place': ''}
2023-04-11 18:54:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 41 pages (at 10 pages/min), scraped 22 items (at 6 items/min)
2023-04-11 18:55:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 41 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 22 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-04-11 18:56:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 41 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 22 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Is there any way to improve it so it does not get stuck?

Comment: Yes, use the API. Also be aware of [IMDb Conditions of Use](https://www.imdb.com/conditions): "Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below."

Comment: @jarmod is for scientific research, so the condition of use may not apply here

Comment: Increase concurrent requests in setting.py

Comment: Give it a try: https://pypi.org/project/PyMovieDb/